# Does C++ have some analog of C# Type thing to store Types of classes in list / array?

Tags: c#, c++, class, types, typeof

In C# i can create such List to store class types:

```
List<Type> types_list = new List<Type>();
types_list.add(typeof(int));
types_list.add(typeof(Process)); //and etc
```

can i do the same in C++?

Comment: Depends on what are you going to do with the types later. In C++ you have `typeid` operator which returns `type_info` structure. So, you can have `std::vector<type_info> v; v.push_back(type_id(Process)); etc.` but there's little you'll be able to do with these types later

Comment: is it possible later, basing on type_info to create instance of class that it describes? in C# it: Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Process));

Comment: I knew you were trying to do something like this :) No, the answer is no, you can't do it with `type_info`. It would require heavy metaprogramming, for example `boost::mpl`, but I can't go into the specifics

Comment: that's very bad! that ruins all my plans. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't put html formatting in your code, just indent it by 4 spaces, or select it and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Benjamin Lindley, i got it about the code block, but how to make new lines without br tag then? if i making new lines with "Enter" button, when i post question all new lines disappear

Comment: @Kosmos: It *is* possible with C++, but it's a pain in the ass :)

Comment: @Kosmos: If all your lines are indented by 4 spaces(which is what the `{}` button does), your newlines do not disappear, as you can now see with CharlesB's edit.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley, but what about new lines where is no 4 spaces in plain text? i mean new lines disappear there

Comment: @Kosmos: That's fine to use html there, I was only talking about the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a type list with [boost MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html).
Example:

```
#include <boost mpl stuff>

int main()
{
   typedef boost::mpl::vector<char, int> types;
   typedef boost::mpl::push_back<types, Process>::type newTypes;
   boost::mpl::at_c<newTypes, 2>::type objectOfTypeProcess;

}
```

You really shouldn't use this library unless you know what you're doing, so my example isn't that specific. You might have to spend some time to get used to mpl anyway.

Comment: i think this is the only way for me :P thanks for your solution!

Comment: Although this provides a way to do it, the OP has to understand that C++ is a completely different language to C#, with different restrictions and goals. Boost::mpl does stuff at compile time, so if people expect to read in a file and construct a typelist at runtime, they're in for a dissapointment.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy: I tried to warn... but then, the OP is determined to do it...

Answer (score 2):

See [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) and [`type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info).

Note that you can not use the `type_info` class to create new instances of the type it represents, as C++ have no support for that.

Comment: I'm not so sure that you can't do it with C++. I mean, do you know `boost mpl` that well to maintain that this is impossible?

Comment: You should be able to do something like `if(t==typeid(Foo)) { Foo x; do something with x; }`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I stand by my statement, `typeid` and `type_info` can't be used to create new instances. While only looking at  Boost.mpl right now, it seem to use templates to create typedefs that can be used to create instances. But it's all compile-time magic and not runtime magic.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to create instances dynamically. Inspiring but incomplete code:

```
class TypeProxy {
public:
    virtual ~TypeProxy() = default;

    char* create_default() const { return this->create_default_impl(); }

    template <typename T>
    static scoped_ptr<TypeProxy> CreateProxy ();

private:
    virtual void* create_default_impl() const = 0;
};


// A creator class.
template <typename T>
class Concrete : public TypeProxy {
    void *create_default_impl() const {
        return new T ();
    }
};


// Method to create creator proxies.
template <typename T>
scoped_ptr<TypeProxy> TypeProxy::CreateProxy () {
    return scoped_ptr<TypeProxy> (new Concrete<T>());
}
```

Note that this is just some untested scratch code to show the operational mode. Whether to use `scoped_ptr` is debatable.

You can get more fancy with variadic templates (see e.g. the `emplace[_(front|back)]` functions in C++11), but it will become complicated as virtual function templates are not allowed, but you somehow have to pass over argument lists nevertheless.

(sidenote: `boost::shared_ptr` use a similar virtual/template mix, which is why you can use non-polymorphic base classes and custom deleters with it)

Comment: that's interesting thing! thanks for showing it. i should look more into that after playing with boost:mpl